# Local variable cause memory leak with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, local-variables

I have a simple question with no answer.

I have a UIAlertView local variable like this,

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                message:@"message"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cancelButtonTitle"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"otherButtonTitle", nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

When I execute the `- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender` method, every time the reference count of the UIAlertView is increased one by one and they are not discarded.

So, any issue is on this with ARC. I need to keep the living objects count without increase while I execute the `- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender` method.

Comment: And you're definitely compiling with ARC enabled on that source file?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled ARC and this is a sample project which has generated using xcode.